# What kind of indexes will help me in this MERGE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a table like this:

```
Name | TimeA | TimeB | ValueA | ValueB
```

And, I am performing some `MERGE` operations as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE #TEMP1...

  INSERT INTO #TEMP1
  SELECT Name, Value
  FROM dbo.AnotherTable
  WHERE ...

  MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable AS Target
    USING (SELECT Name, Value FROM #TEMP1) AS Source
    ON Target.Name = Source.Name
    AND Target.TimeA = @TimeA
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET ValueA = Value
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Name, TimeA, TimeB, ValueA)
    VALUES (Source.Name, @TimeA, @TimeB, Value)
```

The Query Execution Plan says the following:

```
MERGE -> Table Merge 3% -> Compute Scalar 0% -> 
Top 0% -> Compute Scalar 0% -> Compute Scalar 0% ->
Nested Loops (Left Outer Join) 0% <- Constant Scan 0%
              ^
              |
              |
              --- Compute Scalar 0% <- Table Spool (Kager Spool) 12% <- Table Scan 86%
```

The plan, however does not tell me that an index will improve the performance. I'm thinking an unclustered index on `(Name,TimeA)` should improve performance. Is there a better way to achieve performance for MERGE queries like this?

**EDIT 1**: I should note the sizes of the tables. On an average Source always contains 30-70 rows on an average and Target contains > 30 million rows.

Comment: i dont think indexes will help you on merging in general, because it requires a full table scan.

Comment: @Woot4Moo where did you pull that nugget of information?

Comment: @Zane watching my databases melt when trying to merge ~200+ million records into a 1 billion record database + the explain plan that gets generated.

Comment: @Woot4Moo That's **your** observed behaviour for your requirements and database, hardly enough for the *requires a full table scan* to be true

Comment: @Lamak: As much as I was shocked reading that, MSDN does have this piece in the `TOP Clause Best Practices` section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Legend Good find. Though I'm not sure that that link is saying that `MERGE` always performs a table scan or just when you are using  a `TOP`.

Comment: @Legend I believe that bit of wisdom is applicable specifically to TOP and when a merge join is chosen (see the preceding paragraph about other join types that are possible). Paul White shows a couple of plans here where a scan only occurs on one side: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/12/09/merge-bug-with-filtered-indexes.aspx

Comment: @Lamak: +1 Thank you for the clarification. That statement there was a bit ambiguous and depressed me for a second! :)

Comment: How does the MERGE compare to the old-fashioned but equivalent INSERT and UPDATE for execution plans?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: +1 Thank you for the link! Currently reading it and very impressed with the content.

Comment: @woot4Moo Technically the 200 Million should be a scan and if you have an Index on the Colums you are `MERGE`ing on this should not be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider

```
WHEN MATCHED AND ValueA <> Value THEN
```

YOu may be updating records that do not need to be.

Comment: +1 Valid point. Thank you for pointing it out. Would you care to shed some light on whether indexes will help in a MERGE?

Comment: I don't know in this case. YOur temp table cetainily has no indexes, so Iwoudl consider trying to index it and see if that imporves performance, but really not updating 30,000,000 records when you only need to update 20 should make the differnce.

Answer (score 3):

This is here for reference. There are some relevant points that I used to improve my query:

- Using the optimization suggested by @HLGEM. It made total sense.
- Two relevant points from the [MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> To improve the performance of the MERGE statement, we recommend the
> following index guidelines:
>
> - Create an index on the join columns in the source table that is unique and covering.
> - Create a unique clustered index on the join columns in the target table.

- Another point from the same MSDN article that suggested not to place constants in the query

> To filter out rows from the source or target tables, use one of the
> following methods. Specify the search condition for row filtering in
> the appropriate WHEN clause. For example, WHEN NOT MATCHED AND
> S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' THEN INSERT....

Therefore, the indexes I added were:

```
ALTER TABLE #TEMP1
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TEMP1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(ELEMENTINSTANCE, ifAlias)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable
ON dbo.MyTable(Name)
```

And my final query was this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable AS Target
  USING (SELECT Name, Value FROM #TEMP1) AS Source
  ON Target.Name = Source.Name
WHEN MATCHED AND ValueA <> Value AND Target.TimeA = @TimeA THEN
  UPDATE SET ValueA = Value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Name, TimeA, TimeB, ValueA)
  VALUES (Source.Name, @TimeA, @TimeB, Value)
```

This gives me the following execution plan:

```
MERGE -> Table Merge 3% -> Compute Scalar 0% -> 
Top 0% -> Compute Scalar 0% -> Compute Scalar 0% ->
Nested Loops (Left Outer Join) 0% <- Table Scan (#TEMP1) Source 12%
              ^
              |
              |
              --- Compute Scalar 0% <- Clustered Index Seek (dbo.MyTable) 12%
```

Thank you everyone for your help! Hopefully this should maintain the performance for sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I have found, by spending a great deal of time creating indexes that didn't improve performance, that when SSMS generates a query plan, and doesn't recommend an index to create, no index is going to help. This isn't always the case, but often is.

Having said that, your problem can be quite easily solved by trying some indexes, going into Profiler, and checking some metrics like total reads. See what helps and what doesn't. Without seeing a complete schema, and row counts in various tables, we can't be much help. Besides, I think merging often requires table scans which no index will help.

Comment: FYI: I did not down vote (+1ed for your time). To add more information, this table contains over 30 million rows and each MERGE is expected to UPDATE/INSERT about 20 rows on an average.

Comment: Where is this idea coming from that `MERGE` would automatically require a full table scan instead of using the available indexes to search for the appropriate rows? I could be mistaken but I'm fairly certain this is not the case.

Comment: SSMS is just Management Studio. It doesn't generate a query plan and also it doesn't recommend any index, it's just a development tool. PS: Merge is (behind the books) a combined Insert/Delete/Update statement which can and will use a proper index to seek the proper data.

Comment: @Marian: So the statement that MSDN has in the `TOP Clause Best Practices` section here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx is not applicable to my case then?

Comment: @Legend: I believe that Aaron and the other colleagues already answered. That MSDN article is a bit unclear, so don't take it by heart.

Comment: You can force the MERGE to use indexes at the "USING <table> with (index <index1> ...) as tgt"

<merge_hint>::=
{
    { [ <table_hint_limited> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ [ , ] { INDEX ( index_val [ ,...n ] ) | INDEX = index_val }]
    }
}